# Where is the RHS Linux File System Manager?

Tags: linux

The [manual](https://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/5.1/en/os/i386/doc/rhmanual/manual/doc066.htm#s9.2) for Red Hat Linux 5.1 (*Manhattan*) from 1998 (not to be confused with RHEL 5.1), refers to a file system configuration tool called "FSM":

> #### 9.2 File System Configuration
>
> The file system configuration tool shown in Figure [52](https://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/5.1/en/os/i386/doc/rhmanual/manual/doc066.htm#f52) allows you to easily examine and manipulate file system mount points, types, options, etc. It is very useful for manipulating a large number of file systems. You probably don't want to do this unless you are an experienced system administrator. If you do know what you are doing, it should be fairly straightforward as to how to mount, unmount, and add devices.
>
> The **Reload** entry in the **FSM** menu causes the file system configuration tool to re-load
> `/etc/fstab` from your hard drive. If you edit /etc/fstab by hand while the file system configuration tool is running (which you shouldn't do), you probably want to reload.
>
> To use the buttons along the bottom of the window, select a filesystem in the main window, and click on one of the buttons. The buttons perform the following functions:
>
> - **Info**: Displays information on the filesystem, including the device, partition type, filesystem type, mount point and options, comment, size, percent used, etc.
> - **Check**: Performs a filesystem check (`fsck`) on the partition. You can do this only on *unmounted* partitions --- if the partition is mounted, you will get an error and you will have to unmount it first.
> - **Mount**: Mounts the selected filesystem.
> - **Unmount**: Unmounts the selected filesystem.
> - **Format**: Creates a new filesystem on the selected partition. This will erase all data on the selected partition! You can do this only on *unmounted* partitions --- if the partition is mounted, you will get an error and you will have to unmount it first.
> - **Edit**: Brings up a dialog box where you can edit the mount point, mount options, comment, etc.

The `/usr/bin/control-panel` does not show an option for this tool.

Figure 52 shows a screenshot of "RHS Linux File System Manager":

[image: RHS Linux File System Manager]

I have tried searching `rpm -qai | egrep -i 'rhs|file|system|manage'` but cannot find it.

Where is this tool ?

---

### Update:

Thanks to @cristian-ciupitu's answer I was able to discover a `/usr/bin/fstool` in the Live directory on the i386 CD.

The actual RPM package file is not on any of the CDs that came with the original box (ie. i386, src, vendor) (https://linuxgazette.net/165/laycock.html).

I was able to get it going by executing the following commands:

```
# mount -t iso9660 -o loop "/backups/iso/Red Hat Linux-Intel 5.1.5.iso" /mnt/iso/redhat/
# cp -a /mnt/iso/redhat/live/ /tmp/
# cd /tmp/live/
# chroot /tmp/live/ bash
# /usr/bin/fstool
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The above workaround is not perfect as fstool invokes `/usr/bin/dfplus` to pull information from the chroot'ed `df` and `fdisk -l` instead of the parent fstab.

I will have to install the RPM if I want it perfect.

FYI here is the package description:

```
[root@r51 /opt]# rpm -qip fstool-2.6-5.noarch.rpm
Name        : fstool                      Distribution: Manhattan
Version     : 2.6                               Vendor: Red Hat Software
Release     : 5                             Build Date: Tue Apr 28 02:33:43 1998
Install date: (not installed)               Build Host: porky.redhat.com
Group       : Utilities/System              Source RPM: fstool-2.6-5.src.rpm
Size        : 73881
Packager    : Red Hat Software <bugs@redhat.com>
Summary     : File System Configuration Tool
Description :
The fstool is a X program for manipulating /etc/fstab. It allows you
to add, delete, and modify amount points. It also lets you mount
and unmount partitions through its graphical interface.
[root@r51 /opt]#
```

---

### FYI:

According to the [Red Hat Linux FAQ](https://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/5.1/en/os/i386/doc/rhmanual/manual/doc120.htm#i1313) (in the Official Red Hat Linux 5.1 Installation Guide appendix), fstools should be removed:

> **E.9.7 When I run fstool, I get a message that says a partition seems to have been deleted and asks if I want to remove it from
> /etc/fstab.**
>
> The fstool program is not working properly with current versions of
> tcl and shouldn't be used. It should have been obsoleted, but slipped
> through the cracks.
>
> ...
>
> You should now remove the fstool program using rpm.
>
> `rpm -e fstool`
>
> Please use cabaret which is a functional working alternative. This
> program is located in /usr/sbin/cabaret and can be executed from the
> command line.

Comment: assuming it just doesn't exist and is a mistake in the documentation: What do you actually want to *do* with it? Maybe ask a separate question about that, where we could actually help you solve the problem you're facing, instead of finding software that's more than 20 years out of date…

Comment: @MarcusMüller I paid USD$178.64 for an original Red Hat 5.1 box and I want to get my money's worth.

Answer (score 2):

File System Configuration Tool is provided by the **fstool** RPM and the executable is `/usr/bin/fstool`.

Assuming you're running the i386 version, you need to run something like:

```sh
rpm -i /.../redhat/linux/5.1/en/os/i386/RedHat/RPMS/fstool-2.6-5.noarch.rpm
```

If you don't have the installation CD, you can download the RPM from https://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/5.1/en/os/

You might have to install other RPMs as well:

```console
# rpm -qpR fstool-2.6-5.noarch.rpm
tcl
tk
perl
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/perl
/usr/bin/wish
```